# how to indent HTML forms on modals

Tags: jquery, css, html

How can I indent the elements on modal.Here is the code 
http://jsbin.com/quwefekoge/3/edit?html,css,output.
Modification i want to do is held all the labels one below the other and textboxes one below the other separately vertically.

Comment: do you need first label then in next row textbox?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: try like this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a width to your labels:

```
.modal-body label {
  width: 200px;
}
```

[**Updated JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/gaganogeki/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much . It customized the design further .But still when i click the '+' button the two text boxes do not get aligned.

Comment: Add `.col-xs-offset-1 {
  padding-left: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}` to the stylesheet: http://jsbin.com/givoqaluqe/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Your welcome. If the answer suits you, please accept it as an answer (using the v-mark on the left of it).